# Node browserless web client which can manage cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, browser

I'm looking for a Node.js module which mimics browser cookie management.

For example when specific server response contains `set-cookie`, it saves cookie in local http contexts and then sets it to all futher requests to that specific server.

In other word, i need something which acts like a browser, but without dom rendering and on Node side.

Comment: The cookie just comes back from the server in a header.  This would not be hard to write yourself on any request you make to/from a particular server.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), it's a "Full web stack, no browser required".

It can run headless and there's [github/sgentle/phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) for usage with node.